# tablulator grid title not fetch uniquely by field

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I table component, you are using a method getTitle(field), which is used to get title using field properties. but when we have multiple column field with same name it return last tittle.

please suggest how can we find title uniquely with multiple column field have same type.

i suggest, you put two parameter in getTitle method like this, get(titleName,field), so we can find column uniquely.

Comment: Where are you finding getTitle() as I cannot see it anywhere in the code? If this is a custom method then you will need to show the code.

Comment: I second what Adrian said, there is no "getTitle" function anywhere in tabulator. You should not use multiple columns that have the same field name, if you want to base multiple columns off the same field then you should be using a mutator to map that value onto a new field